# sync documents in two different phones

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, future, stream-builder

I am looking for some advice as the current methodology to achieve the desired functionality is not working.

I am working on a job application app.

A job is created..
multiple people can apply for the job.

[there are two collections, one for the jobs and one for the job applications]

when a job is fulfilled or closed, the child's job applications should automatically be closed.

the issue that I am having is that if a user is still in the job application when the job is closed, that job application does not know what happened to the parent job, which allows the user to continue to interact with that job, through the job application (undesired result).

if the user exits the job application view and comes back to it, everything works fine.
here is that part of the code::
[incoming data from server not updating local state fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212236/incoming-data-from-server-not-updating-local-state-fields)

is there a way to implement this functionality based on how I implemented it thus far?

[image: sync two phones]

Comment: I'd do some looking into streams and listeners with firebase. You can basically set things up to where when anything happens in a collection or document and gets changed, it'll trigger your function and let you know that something has changed and you should modify your app accordingly.

Comment: thats exactly what I am looking for, do you have a video or anything that shows how to implement that functionality?  thank you!